# Running older windows versions on Android

Tags: windows, operating-system

Read about [running *Windows 95*](http://www.androidbloggr.com/android-games/windows-95-running-on-android/) (blog post seems to be 9-12 months old) and *98, XP* (XDA has few threads) on Android. I'm interested (because of mind mapping software I use on Windows) but don't really have time and 2nd device to test this. Has someone here tried this and can give a overview of what's possible. Do these versions just run? Or can you

- easily install and run  a .exe
- swap data from android filesystem to Windows
- use internet connection

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about running a different operating system on Android hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try running windows 95 or older versions inside [DosBox](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.hystudio.android.dosbox&hl=en).

Of course this would require some knowledge on MS-DOS stuff and some patience and skill..

Here's a good tutorial on how to boot win95 on DosBox. http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=24936 I would suggest you try this first on a desktop machine with dosbox.

Another way would be to run it using [QEMU](http://qemu.org) for android http://www.mobilephonetalk.com/showthread.php?63990-QEMU-for-Android-Runs-Any-OS

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to install and run Windows 3.1, 95 and 98 on Android via the BOCHS emulator. I believe QEMU would work as well.

I've never managed to get the network connection to work. But I can swap data from my Android partitions to Windows partitions and run the EXE files. So in practice, I have to download everything on native Android and then copy it across.

By the way, it is *really* slow. It took me about a day to install Windows, and then to actually boot Windows it generally takes about 10-20 minutes.

I'm really interested to know how far people have got with this - whether anyone ever managed to install Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1?